# Remove pg_lock from postgres 9.6.6 without any PID

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.6

We had a task which was stuck so I used `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid of the process>)` to kill the task. However the lock that the task hold didn't go away and now one of my table is locked.

I am trying to run a `COPY` command on the table and it gets stuck with `wait_event_type = Lock`.

---

System being Used:

> Server: AWS RDS db.m4.xlarge
>   DB: PostgreSQL 9.6.6

---

> select * from pg_locks;

```
locktype      | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |       mode       | granted | fastpath
--------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+------------------+---------+----------
relation      |    16390 |    19694 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | -1/24019935        |       | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f
transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |      24019935 |         |       |          | -1/24019935        |       | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
```

> select * from pg_prepared_xacts where transaction=24019935;

```
transaction |             gid              |           prepared           |  owner   | database
------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------+----------
24019935    | PGDIRTY:dirty_state::9994733 | 2018-06-27 13:40:12.88981-08 | postgres | pg
```

I already tried doing the step suggested in [Remove locks without a pid in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952635/remove-locks-without-a-pid-in-postgres), but it doesn't show any pgid.

I also tried rebooting my database but the lock still persists.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get rid of this lock ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that the lock remains after rebooting your server. If it does, you have some daemon process that created a new lock right after startup

Comment: In that case the `transactionid` should have been different.

Comment: There is no way a lock can survive a reboot of the database server

Comment: That's what my understanding is as well. But I rebooted RDS 3 times already and the query I mentioned above still results same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case, any other poor fellow gets stuck in similar situation. Here's what worked finally for me.

PS: I don't know why the lock didn't go away with restart as mentioned in the comments of the question.

> `ROLLBACK PREPARED (SELECT gid FROM pg_prepared_xacts);`

Explanation: For some reason, the prepared transaction was never rolled back properly even after termination of the PID and reboot of the RDS server (*maybe RDS does some funny reboot and not full db restart ?* ). After I rolled back the prepared transaction manually, the transaction was finally removed, and lock released.

The suggestion mentioned by [Thomas C. G. de Vilhena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205339/thomas-c-g-de-vilhena) in  [Postgresql DROP TABLE doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317114/postgresql-drop-table-doesnt-work) helped me fix it finally.